# How select rows of my vector with conditions in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, statistics, p-value

I have a vector with values ​​between 0 and 1 (the name of my vector is pvals) and I would like to keep the elements of my vector pvals which respect the condition:

> pvals(i) < i/m*alpha

where alpha = 0.05 and m = 1000 (the size of my vector pvals)

how can i do please?
here i create my pvals vector, and indexes i, but after that i don't know how to make what i explained above:

```
pvals = runif(1000, 0, 1)
i = seq(along=pvals)
```

Comment: You mentioned *"dataframe"* in your title and tags, do you have any frames?

Comment: Since you've defined `pvals`, `i`, `alpha`, and `m`, it seems you just need to type in `pvals < i/m*alpha` to start with, then perhaps try `pvals[ pvals < i/m*alpha ]`.

Comment: Let me know if you have issues with the answer below.  Best wishes!

Comment: thanks everyone i have my response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your described question, this should work.

If `m` and `alpha` exist outside of `pvals`:

```
pvals<-pvals[pvals$i < pvals$i/m*alpha,]
```

I hope this helps!